# Regex Validation in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**Below is my rule for password:**

```
return [
    'Password'                  => 'required|min:8|max:100|regex:[a-z{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}]',
    'Password_confirmation'     => 'required|min:8|max:100|regex:[a-z{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}]',
];
```

I am trying to add the rule such that it must have

> 1. atleast one small char
> 2. atleast one big char
> 3. atleast one number
> 4. atleast one special char
> 5. min 8 chars

I tried this and it works `required|confirmed|min:8|max:100|regex:/^[\w]{1,}[\W]{1,}$/`, on a **regex tester software** . but not sure why it does not work in **Laravel**

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use:

```
return [
    'password' => [
        'required',
        'confirmed',
        'min:8',
        'max:50',
        'regex:/^(?=.*[a-z|A-Z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*(_|[^\w])).+$/',
    ]
];
```

Firstly, you do not need to check the confirmation separately. Just use the `confirmed` rule.

The expression you were using was invalid, and had nothing to do with what you wanted. I do suggest you do [some research](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) on regular expressions.

Due to the fact that the expression shown above uses pipes (`|`), you can specify the rules using an array.

**Edit:** You could also use [this expression](/a/31549892/1626250), which appears to have been tested a little more thoroughly.

```
/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/
```

Comment: Setting a low limit on the number of characters a user can use for their password can lead to a bad user experience, especially when the user is using a password manager which generates passwords beyond 20 characters or they want to use a phrase as their password.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to check the [PasswordStrengthPackage](https://github.com/schuppo/PasswordStrengthPackage). It registers new validation rules that do what you need and are much more readable than a regular expression. So in your case you can have this:

```
return [
    'Password' => 'required|min:8|max:100|case_diff|numbers|letters|symbols|confirmed'
];
```

The `Password_confirmation` rule is not needed as long as the confirmation value is present and you add the [`confirmed`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-confirmed) rule for the `Password` field.